# jQuery using .toggle() to toggle a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

So I want to toggle a single element in an array of elements how can I do this?

What I have tried

```
$(".classname")[1].toggle()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with that is that you are getting the element rather than a jquery object. Try this:

```
$(".classname").eq(1).toggle()
```

Also, I assume you are looking for the 2nd element using index 1

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$('.classname').eq(0).toggle()
```

When using `[]`, you are losing jquery reference and the object become a dom element. DOM element are used with Javascript. Example :

```
 $('.classname')[0].id //will work since .id is a DOM attribute
 $('.classname').eq(0).id //will not work since it's a jQuery object
```

Here the [jQuery .eq() information](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) page.

Elements are based on a 0 index, wich mean `0 = first element, 1 = second element and go on`

Comment: OP wants second element I believe